# Do the colder and warmer poles of the CMB's Axis of Evil corresponds to the terrestrial poles?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, cosmic-microwave-background

Does the terrestrial North or South Pole correspond to the colder and warmer poles in the CMB, as differentiated by the 'axis of evil'? If so, which to which?

Comment: How could that be? Surely if the axis is aligned with the ecliptic then our North Pole must point to the CMB's cold or hot pole?  Or am I missing something basic here... is the CMB not localized in our celestial sky anywhere at all?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background#CMBR_dipole_anisotropy_(%E2%84%93_=_1)

Answer (score 2):

The so-called axis of evil in the cosmic microwave background is an axis approximately perpendicular to the plane of the Earth's orbit around the Sun. The ecliptic north pole does not coincide with the terrestrial north pole, since the Earth's spin axis is inclined to its orbital axis by 23.5 degrees.

The celestial north pole is closer to the ecliptic north pole, which is slightly cooler in the CMB (after removal of the dipole signature due to the Earth's motion).

Comment: So the terrestrial North Pole is offset, but it is correct that the general northern hemisphere of earth approximately corresponds with the slightly cooler pole of the CMB?

Comment: @Svenn The celestial north pole is closer to the ecliptic north pole, which is slightly cooler in the CMB.